# Drag and Drop Reorder in KendoUI list view

Tags: listview, drag-and-drop, kendo-ui

Hy, I am new to KendoUI and I am trying to reorder a listView with drag and drop. I notice that the listVIew plugin does not have draggable features in its CORE so I am trying to add the Draggable actions from Kendo Framework but I am not even close.

Is it possible to reorder the listView items with Drag and Drop?

[Kendolistview](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/listview/index.html) and [Kendo Drag](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dragdrop/index.html)

I notice that one of KendoUI plugins does have this feature:

[TreeView Demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/dragdrop.html)

PS: A demo or something similar is very welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need that not only behave as a ListView but being an actual ListView you might do:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data    : products,
    pageSize: 10
});

$("#listView").kendoListView({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    template  : kendo.template($("#template").html()),
    dataBound : function () {
        $(".product").kendoDraggable({
            hint: function (element) {
                return element.clone();
            }
        });
    }
});

$("#listView").kendoDropTargetArea({
    filter: ".product",
    drop  : function (e) {
        var srcUid = e.draggable.element.data("uid");
        var dstUid = e.dropTarget.data("uid");
        var srcItem = dataSource.getByUid(srcUid);
        var dstItem = dataSource.getByUid(dstUid);
        var dstIdx = dataSource.indexOf(dstItem);
        dataSource.remove(srcItem);
        dataSource.insert(dstIdx, srcItem);
        e.draggable.destroy();

    }
});
```

Basically we identify each element with the CSS class `.product` and then we use it for inserting it and removing it from the DataSource. This automatically redraw it.

See running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/MYbgy/1/

Comment: This is amazing, small and clean. Exactly what I asked for.

Comment: Might but we need to solve how to move from one page to another while dragging the item. How do you plan to do it? Normally is pressing page numbers but this time that's not (easily) possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this might work:

```
$("#sortable").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource :dataSource,
    template   :"<div class='ob-item'> #= item.text # </div>",
    dragAndDrop:true,
    drag       :function (e) {
        var dst = $($(e.dropTarget).closest(".k-item")[0]).data("uid");
        var src = $(e.sourceNode).data("uid");
        if ($(e.dropTarget).hasClass("ob-item") && dst != src) {
            e.setStatusClass("k-insert-top");
        } else {
            e.setStatusClass("k-denied");
        }
    },
    drop       :function (e) {
        if ($(e.sourceNode).data("uid") !== $(e.destinationNode).data("uid")) {
            $(e.sourceNode).insertBefore(e.destinationNode);
        }
        e.setValid(false);
    }
});
```

Also some information [here](http://onabai.wordpress.com/2012/10/26/kendoui-sortable-lists/)

Comment: This works with TREEVIEW, I am searching for a LISTVIEW solution :)